# runtime error 91 when excuting the code

Tags: vb6

When executing the following code in VB6, I am getting 'Run-time error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set'. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub btn_Test_Click()
    Dim dt As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "select * from Reg_User"
    Set dt = myconn.getdatatab(sql)      ' here i am getting error
End Sub
```

The class code is

```
Private provider As String
Private dt As ADODB.Recordset
Private Const DEF_LOCKTYPE = adLockReadOnly
Private Const DEF_CURSORTYPE = adOpenKeyset

Public Function getdatatab(sql As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnnmain As ADODB.Connection

    cnnmain.Open "Driver=SQL Server;uid=sa;pwd=abcd;Database=Test;Server=pos001-pc\SQLEXPRESS2;"

    Set dt = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set dt.ActiveConnection = cnnmain
    dt.Open sql, , DEF_CURSORTYPE, DEF_LOCKTYPE
    If dt.EOF And dt.BOF Then
        Set getdatatab = dt
    Else
        dt.MoveFirst
        Set getdatatab = dt
    End If
    cnnmain.Close

End Function
```

Comment: where is the `myconn` object instanciated?

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT AFTER PROVIDING THE PROPER CODE]

You must instantiate a class before using an object variable. It looks like you had tried to use `cnnmain` without instantiating it.

The code fragment:

```
Public Function getdatatab(sql As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnnmain As ADODB.Connection

    cnnmain.Open "Driver=SQL Server;uid=sa;pwd=abcd;Database=Test;Server=pos001-pc\SQLEXPRESS2;"  ' <====== ERROR OCCURS HERE
    ...
End Function
```

... should be:

```
Public Function getdatatab(sql As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnnmain As ADODB.Connection

    Set cnnmain = New ADODB.Connection
    cnnmain.Open "Driver=SQL Server;uid=sa;pwd=abcd;Database=Test;Server=pos001-pc\SQLEXPRESS2;"  ' <====== ERROR OCCURS HERE
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for respond, **myconn** is the object of my class instantated in the form global. and i am using the **getdatatab** function to get data. in the function i am Instantiate the connection. Please view my above code.

Comment: @user3463529 No you don't instantiate a connection in `getdatatab`, you only declare it.

Comment: Ok - is this the *real* code? Because in what I am seeing, that .Open() method *will* raise an error.

Comment: this is Real code i have done like this in 18 win forms all are working good.I dont know what you are think about **open**, this is will read the connection string(or connect with).same i have used in 18 forms all are working good.

Comment: If you haven't instantiated cnnmain, how can you call the Open() method on it without raising an error?

Comment: GSerg -  **getdatatab**  is the one function in my class. and **myconn** is the class object. if i only declare, how can i get the function name, when class object not having all the functions in class.

Comment: Mr Mark - i used **open** to access Connection String in my class. i am unable to cath your intention, please explain it.

Comment: There is no such concept in Visual Basic 6 as "class object". I guess you mean that *myconn* is a *global* object. I don't understand your next sentence at all. As for "instantiation" - that is where you use the New operator to create a new *instance* of a class, e.g. Set cnnmain = New ADODB.Connection. Sorry, I assumed you would understand that. I will update the answer.

Comment: mark- sorry, i am basically C# developer,in this issue Class means Class Module in VB6. any way now i escape from error 91. but i am unable to get data in RecordSet, so nothing show in report.

Comment: Have you ever used the debugger in VB6? Does my revised code fragment work?

Comment: Yes it is working good. there is no doubt.i am thinking why Recordset has no data.